# Matlab and python gives different answer for sind() function

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, trigonometry

I tried searching in the forum and I was not successful in finding the reason why the answers in python are different than in Matlab. I am trying to use sind() function in Matlab, where the user input is in degrees. The Matlab snippet is,

`angle = 27;
b = sind(angle)`

This gives b as 0.4540. 
The equivalent code in python

```
angle = 27;
b = math.degrees(math.sin(angle))
```

I get b as 54.79.

I can't able to fix the problem and any inputs would be highly appreciable.

Best Regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

This is a unit issue. In python, `math.sin()` assumes radians, not degrees. The MATLAB function `sind` specifies degrees. So you need to convert your angle into radians, then take the sine.

Here's the python you need:

```
math.sin(math.radians(27))
```